# reduction of order; not getting right answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use reduction of order or formula 5 to find a second solution $y_2(x)$
Formula 5 is $y_2=y_1(x)\int \frac{e^{-\int P(x) dx}}{y^2_1(x)}dx$ where $P(x)$ is $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$

The ODE is $y''+16y=0$ and the $y_1(x)$ is $cos4x$. The answer key says $y_2=sin4x$ but I don't get this.

Using the formula: $P(x)=0$ so $y_2=cos4x \int \frac{e^{-\int 0 dx}}{cos^2x}dx$ which isn't $sin4x$

Also using reduction of order I get $y=ucos4x, y'=uxcos4x-ux4sin4ux, y''=ucos4x-4u'sin4x-u'4sin4ux-u16cos4x$. 
Then
$w'cos4x-8wsin4x=0$ then $u'=ce^{-2cos4x}$

This also doesn't work.

Comment: You are mistaken as $$\cos\left(4x\right)\int\sec{4x}\:dx=\sin\left(4x\right).$$ You must have forgotten about the $4$ in the $\cos\left(x\right)$.

Comment: @bd1251252 - it must be $\sec^2{4x}$

Comment: @Dillon You are quite right, my apologies :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula does work. Ignoring constants of integration, note that $e^{\int 0 \, dx} = e^{0} = 1$, so we have:
$$
(\cos 4x)\int \frac{1}{\cos^2 4x} \, dx
= (\cos 4x)\int \sec^2 4x \, dx
= (\cos 4x)(\tfrac{1}{4}\tan 4x)
= \tfrac{1}{4}\sin 4x
$$
which can be scaled by $4$ to get the desired second solution.

Comment: Isn't $\int 0 dx = C \neq 0$?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter. I dropped the constant of integration. If you include it, it will just disappear at the end since we can scale the second solution by any nonzero constant.